# Find a region with maximum sum of top-K points

Tags: geometry, algorithms, computational-complexity

My problem is: we have $N$ points in a 2D space, each point has a positive weight. Given a query consisting of two real numbers $a,b$ and one integer $k$, find the position of a rectangle of size $a \times b$, with edges are parallel to axes, so that the sum of weights of top-$k$ points, i.e. $k$ points with highest weights, covered by the rectangle is maximized?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

P.S.:
There are two related problems, which are already well-studied:

- Maximum region sum: find the rectangle with the highest total weight sum. Complexity: $O(N\log N)$.
- top-$k$ query for orthogonal ranges: find top-$k$ points in a given rectangle. Complexity: $O(\log^2 N + k)$.

Comment: Your last edits didn't do anything significant to the post. Since each edit bumps the question on the front page and thereby pushes another question off it, please avoid such trivial edits. Restrict yourself to substantial edits.

Comment: I'd be interested in a link that gives $O(N\log N)$ complexity (highest sum), thanks.

Comment: @ringø You can find it [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089812219500029X)